# How to compare each events in stream, streamController dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem (example):

> Given nums = [2, 11, 7, 15], target = 9,
>   Because nums[0] + nums[2]
>   = 2 + 7 = 9,    return [0, 2].

I wrote a hardcode which solve this problem:

```
void twoSumHardCode(List<int> nums, int target){
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
      if(nums[j] == target - nums[i]){
        print([i, j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to solve this problem with Stream, StreamController. how do i compare first events with subsequent ones. Cause I'm new in stream and so far I understand not very well, how can I rewrite a 'hardcode' to 'streamcode'..

I wrote a little:

```
void twoSum(List<int> nums, int target){

  final controller = new StreamController();
  nums.map((int num) => controller.sink.add(num));

  final transformer = StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (number, sink){
//      final List<int> indices = []

    }
  );

  controller.stream.
      map((number){
        //
      })
      .transform(transformer)
      .listen((numbers) => print(numbers));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Streams are not intended for that purpose. Your problem needs (in memory) all the values ever emmited by the stream, right?

So, for that you must convert your stream into a `List`, waiting for all its values to be emmited.

```dart
   Stream<int> numbers() async* {
      for (var num in [2, 11, 7, 15]) {
        yield num;
      }
    }

    void main() async {

      var list = await numbers().toList();

      twoSumHardCode(list, 9);

    }
```

Also, if you need to keep the emmited values cached for some reason, you can use `rxdart` library's `ReplaySubject`.